# recommendation on good LDAP training, preferably with concentrating on OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap

I need to bring in someone to train my team with the usage of LDAP.
Any objective recommendations on a company/freelance that gives such a service?
in the USA/dc

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk to symas.com folks. They are the best.

http://www.symas.com/services.shtml